# Search part of string in a column and delete the row in vba code

Tags: vba, excel

I am searching for the part of the string and based on only the part of string it must delete the row.
I have more than 10000 rows.please consider that and write the code
The sample data:

```
      A               B                C
    Fname            Lname            Username
1. Thomas            Frauen           thomas@gmail.com
2. anne              schmidt          anne@rediff.com
3. olaf              geissler         olaf@yahoo.com
```

I Know only the username string part i.e "@yahoo.com" . Would like to delete the row 3.

Here is my code.

```
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
row_number = 1

username = sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & row_number)

if instr(username, "*@yahoo.com*") = true then
   Sheets("sheet1").Rows(row_number & ":" & row_number).Delete
   row_number = row_number - 1
End If
```

can anyone help me out, pls.

Comment: do you also have a loop around your if-condition?

Comment: if this is a one-off activity, consider to define auto filters, search for yahoo and delete all/some of the displayed/filtered rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to use `instr` without your wildcards. Everything in "" is considered as part of the searchstring

you do also require a loop. take this code, it's working for your problem.

```
Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For row_number = Lastrow To 1 Step -1
    UserName = Sheets("sheet1").Range("C" & row_number).Value
    If InStr(1, UserName, "@yahoo.com", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
       Sheets("sheet1").Rows(row_number & ":" & row_number).Delete           
    End If
Next row_number
```

Comment: it throwing an error as "type mismatch". Is there any other alternative code

Comment: could you please explain the part of inside "if statement". what exactly it do?

Comment: search for the string "@yahoo.com" within the variable `UserName` start at the character position `1` and compare text only (no ascii code, no case sensitivity). Return is the character position where the search string `"@yahoo.com"` starts. If return value > 0 => search string found.
you can find the information here too: <http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/instr.php>